# Replicating a browser https request in javascript

Tags: javascript, browser, cors

I'm trying to hit an API that needs a cookie to return data.

If i hit the url directly in the browser I get the data i want. The protocol is https.

However, whenever I try to fetch the data using `window.fetch` I run into CORS errors. I think this is happening because I cant get the cookie in the client request, which is causing the server to redirect to an auth server that is not sending back a CORS header.

I have tried using `{ credentials: 'include' }` to no avail.

I was assuming that because the cookie exists in the browser it will be part of the request.

Any fundamental knowledge I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

hmm this is a bit weird, by default `fetch` uses `{ credentials: 'same-origin' }` which will allow cookies to be sent `{ credentials: 'include' }` also will send cookies even if its not the same origin and that's the only difference.

what i am thinking here is that either somewhere in your code the cookie gets deleted somehow or your request is firing before the cookie is set, or the server doesn't allow CORS or it doesn't allow the OPTIONS method if its a different origin.